# Rotating view controller

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hi i am making navigation based application and i want to rotate a child view controller i am using following code but when i rotate the device these function cannot be called

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 

{

// return YES;

return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

{

NSLog(@"didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation");

if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)



{

        portraitMode = NO;

        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            [self unloadPage:j];

        [self loadLandScrollViewWithPage:pageInt-1];
        [self loadLandScrollViewWithPage:pageInt];
        [self loadLandScrollViewWithPage:pageInt+1];

        [fullSizeView setHidden:NO];

        CGRect frame = l_mageScrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageInt;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        [l_mageScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        portraitMode = YES;

        [fullSizeView setHidden:YES];

        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            [self unloadPage:j];

        //[l_mageScrollView setHidden:NO];
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:pageInt-1];
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:pageInt];
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:pageInt+1];

        CGRect frame = imageScrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageInt;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        [imageScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added this child view controller as a sub view then these method won't be called. But these `UIViewController` methods will be called in the parent view controller

Comment: you can try rotating the sub view in the parent view controller class methods

Answer (score 0):

If you have added this child view controller as a sub view then these method won't be called.

Its only call in parent view (rootview).

Answer (score 0):

When you `return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);`, you're telling the view controller that it should never rotate to any orientation besides portrait.  If you want it to rotate to all orientations, return `YES` from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`